# Add noise to categorical data in tf / Keras?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, categorical-data

Just being curious about adding noise to categorical variables. I suspect that adding gaussian noise over a one hot encoded variable wouldn't be enough. I was thinking about adding noise after embedding the categorical variables. After trying this, my results are not really improving. I suspect that the best solution would be to switch the one hot encoded variable randomly to another column. However it is unclear how to achieve this with tf keras.

Are there any other approach to adding noise to a categorical variable ?
Regarding the last idea, is there any easy way to do this or do I have to build a custom layer ?

Answer (score 2):

You can first take the one-hot representation. You can assimilate this to a probability distribution of a categorical random variable, where one option has probability 1 so any samples we draw would be that value.

Then, you would use the [Gumbel-Softmax trick](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.01144.pdf) to add noise to the distribution and sample from it. This is an implementation taken from [here](https://alexgl-github.github.io/github/jekyll/2021/03/23/Gumbel-Softmax.html):

```
class Sample_Softmax(Model):

    def __init__(self, num_values=5, tau=1.0):
        super(Sample_Softmax, self).__init__()
        self.tau = tau
        self.arange = tf.range(start=0, limit=num_values, dtype=tf.float32)

    def call(self, x):
        # generate  gumbel noise
        noise = np.random.gumbel(size=x.shape)
        noisy_x = x + noise

        # apply softmax temperature
        noisy_x =  noisy_x / self.tau

        # compute softmax
        probs = K.exp(noisy_x) / K.sum(K.exp(noisy_x))

        # dot product for the index of max array element
        index = tf.tensordot(probs, self.arange, axes=1)

        return index
```

Another option would be to take the result of the softmax and multiply it directly by the embedding matrix to obtain an embedded vector representation that is a weighted average according to the obtained noisy probabilities.

As an optional step, before applying the Gumbel noise, you may want to smooth the probability distribution with label smoothing:

```
def smooth_labels(labels, factor=0.1):
    labels *= (1 - factor)
    labels += (factor / labels.shape[1])
    return labels
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about this. I understand it's a way of smoothing. I was mor elooking for 'swap' noise and its configuration.

Comment: The effect of the `Sample_Softmax` function is precisely "swap noise".

Comment: Hmm ok. I'll look into this. It seems to be better than what I expected. I was thinking something along the lines of permutation.